# Funcion replace en mysql no funciona

Tags: mysql, replace

Trabajo con mysql workbench 8.0
al lanzar un comando simple "replace".
Ejemplo:

```
select replace(nombre, 'e', 'EEP') as nombre from producto;
```

La consulta la compila bien (No devuelve ningun mensaje de error)
pero no devuelve la tabla con la modificación.
Devuelve la tabla según estaba en un principio, como si no hubiera lanzado dicho comando: select replace...

Sería buena idea acceder desde la shell de mysql por si es algo relacionado con el mysqlworkbench propiamente dicho?

Algun idea?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo minimo para reproducir el problema????

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! nos das un ejemplo de datos, la entrada que tenes y la salida que recibis???

Comment: Pero quieres que tu query actualice las 'e' por 'EEP' en el nombre del producto de la base de datos? O solo quieres reemplazar y que lo muestre? Si es lo primero lo estas haciendo mal, si es lo segundo tu query funciona perfectamente.

Comment: No olvides [edit] tu pregunta proporcionando datos de prueba, el resultado esperado, y el resultado obtenido, para poder comprender mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: `SELECT nombre FROM producto WHERE nombre LIKE '%e%';` devuelve algún resultado?

Comment: Podes poner un ejemplo para que lo podamos probar?? probaste por ejemplo si online te pasa lo mismo???

Comment: Tu *cotejamiento* (collate) ¿es insensible a mayúsculas?.

Comment: Hola Alo Malbarez la salida de: SELECT nombre FROM producto WHERE nombre LIKE '%e%';  funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer la **opción Safe Updates** también puede afectar a las **consultas select** en caso de estar habilitada.

Para desactivar la **opción Safe Updates** debes hacer lo siguiente:

Dentro del **MySQL Workbench** da clic en el **menú Edit** y selecciona **Preferences**.

Una vez abierta la **ventana Preferences** selecciona **SQL Editor** en el panel izquierdo.

Posteriormente deshabilita la **opción Safe Updates** en el panel derecho y haz clic en Ok para guardar los cambios realizados.

## Actualización:

También puede ser que tengas una consulta colgada, y esto demore en exceso la ejecución de tu nueva consulta, asegúrate de matar ese proceso supuestamente activo y prueba de nuevo tu consulta.

Comment: bueno.. supongamos que esto es correcto... yo no recomendaria eso, nunca!!!! no funciona si se pone where 1=1???

Comment: @gbianchi puede ser, y que pasa entonces si haces delete from tabla where 1=1,  ocurre exactamente el mismo desastre, pierde todos los registros

Comment: la opción Safe Updates ya estaba deshabilitada. la instrucción continua sin hacer los cambios.
Gracias!

Comment: en caso de safeUpdate `WHERE 1` o `WHERE 1=1` no son safe pues no incluyen keys. (*) a menos que `1` sea el nombre de una columna y uses quotes para que no se interprete como número ```where `1` = 1``` . Si se quiere modificar todos los registros se puede hacer un `WHERE campo_clave IS NOT NULL`

Comment: La opción Safe Updates ya estaba deshabilitada. La query es simplemente para que reemplace y muestre sin realizar ninguna actualizacion en la base de datos. Igualmente la salida del select continua igual, se le indica que reemplaze 'e' por 'EEP'. no devuelve errores pero la salida no es la esperada. No hay reemplazo gracias

Comment: just in case, verifica que el resutlado de la consulta no esté en otro tab.